# How to remove a file and directory using command line arguments

Tags: python

I am trying to remove image from directory using the code below but it not doing what i want

```
import os
import sys
count = 0
for arg in sys.argv:
    for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(arg):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
                count = count + 1
                thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
                os.remove(thefile)
print('Files:', count)
print('Files removed')
```

It is not throwing up any error and still not removing the file

Comment: Are you *passing* the full path to the directory?

Comment: It looks to work here in a single folder, But not with subfolders.

Comment: use `print()` to check values in variables. You can also see which part of code is executed. If file has extension `.JPG` then it will not match to `.endswith('.jpg')`. You may have to check lower case - `filename.lower().endswith('.jpg')`

Comment: The code seems right. I run it and it works too. Probably you are giving the wrong path in the args when you are running the program.

Comment: The outermost loop is just useless, you can simply use `for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):` to get list of all files and folders in your directory, why bother passing each argument to `os.walk()`

Comment: I will try it out and see but how exactly will it affect the efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY:**

```
import os
import sys
count = 0

# Path for os.walk() is obtained via commandline parameter 1 
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
            count += 1
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            os.remove(thefile)

print('Files:', count)
print('Files removed')
```

**EXECUTING THE CODE:-**

```
-> ImageRemover.py "C:\Users\lol\Pictures"
```

General syntax for executing your script = `'python_script_location' 'image_dir_location'`
The Second Argument will be the location of your image file directory.

**CHANGES:-**

Removed redundant outermost `for` loop to provide just the path of `image_dir` to `os.walk()` and hence make the process more efficient.

**THINGS TO REMEMBER:-**

1. Provide the full path of the source directory (considered as a good measure)
2. Make sure the file extension is a correct one, and the one that you want. ex. if your image files are of `.png` extension change `if filename.lower().endswith('.jpg')` to `if filename.lower().endswith('.png')`
3. Make sure you are using commandline, to execute the script, otherwise the script will execute but will always show this output:-

   **Files: 0**

   **Files removed**

Comment: My hypothesis is that you are not executing the script via `commandline`, and just running the script by itself, due to which the file always gets executed but nothing happens as no arguments are provided to it

Comment: Great job, your post help me a lot, it's working now, also i was not passing the argument properly on cmd. Thanks man